# Azure DevOps Git - Archive multiple repositories

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have several repositories (around 10) which I would like to archive. By "archive", I mean moving them to a new repo called "archive. If I `git archive` them, they would be made read-only but still be listed in my repos.And I would like to avoid that to let my team see only the active repos and also to keep the list short. So, can you please suggest a way to move several repos to a new repo and preserve their history? Thank you!

Comment: I think this is a git question. See my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, can you please suggest a way to move several repos to a new repo
> and preserve their history?

yes, these is. And I think this question is basically a git question.

You can first git clone all of your repository to local(Include the repository you want to move to).

For example, you git clone two repositories named testrepo1 and testrepo2:

[image]

And you want to merge testrepo1 to testrepo2 and keep the histories, just follow the below steps:

```
cd testrepo2
git remote add testrepo1 <Absolute path of testrepo1>
git fetch testrepo1 --tags
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories testrepo1/main
git push
```

[image]

Ten repositories is not very much, you can manually do the above steps, or you can write code to auto run the above steps(If you use script, please make sure you give the script enough time to do git operation, otherwise something will missing.).

**PS:**

Just notice, [--allow-unrelated-histories](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---allow-unrelated-histories) is only available when git >= 2.9, otherwise you will be unable to use this.

Comment: OK, I have several repos with all following the same tagging semver strategy like 0.1.0. I am not too concerned about tags. After I merge my first repo with tag 0.1.0 and push it to my new repo and I try with the same steps, I get this 
on fetching --tags: ` ! [rejected]        0.1.0      -> 0.1.0  (would clobber existing tag)`
on merge : `merge: <my-second-repo> - - not something we can merge`. Any advice? Thanks

Comment: @ParthSekar Hi. I can reproduce the issue, but I can avoid this issue and merge tag successfully on my side. Do you try to merge testrepo1/tagname instead of tagname directly? Anyway, please notice the output of the command.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I moved my repos to my archive repo in a hierarchical fashion:

```
> cd /path/to/target/repo
> git fetch /path/to/source/repo main
> git merge -s ours --no-commit --allow-unrelated-histories FETCH_HEAD
> git read-tree --prefix=new-folder-name/ -u FETCH_HEAD
> git commit -m "merged <repo-name> into <target-branch>"
> git push
```

The below link has more detailed explanations on each of the commands.

Reference: [merging git repositories at different directory levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929071/merging-git-repositories-at-different-directory-levels)